# Prove that if the real part of a holomorphic function is bounded so is the imaginary part, without using Liouville's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if the real part of an entire function is bounded so is the imaginary part, without using Liouville's theorem.

In particular, is there a way to prove this using the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: By "holomorphic" do you mean "entire"? And would you allow Casorati-Weierstrass into the game?

Comment: entire, yes, just edited. Using Casorati-Weierstrass is in a different direction than what I'm looking for, but I'm definetely interested if you have the time to write it down.

Comment: Can you use integration?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this and if you consider properties of harmonic functions as a consequence of Cauchy-Riemman equations (one can use the equations to show that real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic), then we can show it 'without Liouville's theorem'. It can be thought of as a consequence of the mean value property (rather than an estimate on coefficients of the power series).

That said, Liouville's theorem **is** essentially about harmonic functions, so I'm not quite sure this answers your question or even if it *can* be answered in a satisfactory way.